# Unwanted property sharing in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My code dynamically sizes the widgets before putting them in a parent view. The width is simply calculated as an integer for each widget and independently assigned. The problem is that when a larger widget appears, all the previous ones size exactly the same, even though they are already placed and untouched.
I turned on a debugger to investigate. Turns out the width of each widget is placed in one place in the memory. So they all are practically the same and changing it for one widget causes others to change appropriately. Here is a dirty app that represents an issue:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Builder.load_string('''        
<ScrollView>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Message>:
    x: 5
    width: 500
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        height: self.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: root.x, root.y
                size: self.width, self.height

        TextInput:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
            id: msg
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
''')

class Chat(Screen):
    pass

class Message(Widget):
    pass

class ChatApp(App):
    def width_modify(self):
        min_width = 160
        max_width = 320
        max_line = 0
        for i in self.msg_stack[-1].ids['msg']._lines_labels:
            if i.width > max_line:
                max_line = i.width
        curr_width = max_line + 15
        return curr_width

    def msg_in(self, btn):
        msg_stack = self.msg_stack
        msg = self.tx1_main.text.strip("\n ")
        msg_stack.append(Message())
        msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].text = msg

        msg_stack[-1].size_hint = [None, None]
        msg_stack[-1].width = self.width_modify()
        msg_stack[-1].height = (len(msg_stack[-1].ids['msg']._lines_labels) + 1) * (msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].line_height)
        for i in msg_stack[-1].walk():
            i.height = msg_stack[-1].height
            i.width = msg_stack[-1].width

        msg_stack[-1].y = self.sv1_main.height - 5 - self.pr_msg_y - msg_stack[-1].height

        self.msg_layout.add_widget(msg_stack[-1])
        self.pr_msg_y += msg_stack[-1].height + 5


    def build(self):
        self.msg_stack = []
        self.pr_msg_y = 5

        self.chat = Chat()
        self.tx1_main = TextInput(size_hint = (0.9, 0.155))
        self.sv1_main = ScrollView(pos_hint = {"top":0.87, "center_x":0.5},
                                   size_hint = (0.97, 0.65))
        self.msg_layout = GridLayout(height = 10, cols = 1, size_hint_y = None)
        self.msg_layout.bind(minimum_height = self.msg_layout.setter('height')) 

        self.bt1_main = Button(size_hint = (0.061, 0.078),
                               pos_hint = {"top":0.097, "center_x":0.951},
                               on_press = self.msg_in)

        self.chat.add_widget(self.tx1_main)
        self.chat.add_widget(self.sv1_main)
        self.sv1_main.add_widget(self.msg_layout)
        self.chat.add_widget(self.bt1_main)
        return self.chat

ChatApp().run()
```

I suspect the problem might be in the kv definition of the Message widget, particularly this line `width: 500`. It is some property I've put for testing purposes and now removing it causes my sizing to break. Also, commenting it out doesn't really seem to solve anything. So what can I do?
This is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ7Xw.jpg) to demonstrate the problem. The red corners shouldn't extend

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the expected behaviour is and how this does not behave as expected? When I run it, I can enter strings at the bottom, and when I click on the button, messages appear, each about a long as needed to display the string.

Comment: width is already a NumericProperty of Widget, not something you can avoid. And the property is a descriptor anyway (it behaves as a normal instance attribute mostly), being a property won't cause your problem.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez If you first enter a string and press the button, you will see the red boundaries of the widget. If you then write some more text and press again, you will see that the boundaries of the first one extended, which is not what I want. I want them to stay independent from each other.

Comment: @inclement I understand. But since every widget is different from the others, why are all the `Message` widgets sharing a single space in the memory to store their `width` property?

Comment: What is the single space in the memory? If it points at the Property object, that's because this object internally stores the widths for each instance in different places.

Comment: That's not what I see. Adding new messages does not affect the size of existing ones. I'm running v1.9.2-dev0, at a pretty recent commit from github.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I'm running v1.9.1, could that be a bug in Kivy?

Comment: @inclement `<kivy.properties.NumericProperty 0x2b732d0>` is what I see in the debugger as the width of every `Message` widget, `0x2b732d0` being that place in the memory

Comment: That sounds fine and normal. Again, NumericProperty is a descriptor that gives instance-level behaviour by storing separately the widths of each instance.

Comment: @inclement But it's supposed to store each instance's width in a separate `NumericProperty`, which isn't the case here. The `canvas` property for each `Message` widget, for example, is stored in separate places, but other properties are shared

Comment: @inclement [Here](http://imgur.com/tmuEqDY) I've highlighted the matching memory slots. That "1" with an arrow delimits two separate instances of `Message` class. And they aren't sharing a place in the memory, so I assume their properties shouldn't as well

Comment: No, it is expected that (as properties are class level) one property instance is shared by all the class instances.

Comment: And the canvas isn't shared because it isn't a Kivy property, just an instance-level attribute.

Comment: The `NumericProperty` object does not store any values at all. Values are stored on a separate, private cdef attribute (`__storage`) on each individual object using the property.

Comment: Use Inspector to check the actual values of properties. https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html

Comment: @inclement So why does the widgets' width depend on other instances? Shouldn't those `__storage` properties be unchangeable from accessing other instances?

Comment: @Leva7 it isn't clear they depend on other instances. Have you tried using the current development version of kivy? So far, nobody has confirmed the behaviour you describe for your example.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez So far, only you have commented about recreating this issue. I might switch to the latest version, but I expected the issue to be on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest development version of Kivy (`v1.9.2-dev0`) seems to fix the problem